# How to manipulate a plot (Histogram) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I'm stuck on an assignment where I have to manipulate a plot. I'd like to add a vertical line over the dates in the x-axis that corresponds to holidays and maybe add a horizontal line on the vertical line that corresponds to 4-6 days and 14 days respectively.

THIS IS MY CODE IN R:

```
#### Load Libraries ####

library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)
library(gdata)
library(ggplot2)

#### Load Data ####

Covid_19 <- read.csv("WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv")


#### Encode the Data Properly to Show Accents ####

Encoding(Covid_19$Country) <- "UTF-8"

unique(Covid_19$Country)


#### Create New Data Frame With Just The Data I Wish To Examine ####

Covid_19_USA <- subset(Covid_19, Country_code=="US")


#### Change The Column Name Into Something Legible ####

colnames(Covid_19_USA)[1] <- "Dates"


#### Change The Format to Date Format ####

Covid_19_USA$Dates <- as.Date(Covid_19_USA$Dates)


#### Check The Data for Structure ####

summary(Covid_19_USA)


#### PLot The Data to Observe any Anomaly or Trend ####

plot(Covid_19_USA$Dates, Covid_19_USA$New_cases, xlab = "Date (From January - August)", ylab = "New Cases", main = "USA Daily New Cases", type = "h")
```

[This is the crappy attempt at showing what I would like to learn how to do in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGZy9.png)

Comment: You can look into geom_hline() and geom_vline() to add either horizontal or vertical lines.

Comment: @Dealec Thank you very much for commenting on my post and trying to help. But I'm a newbie as in 4 weeks ago I began to use R. Could you be specific? I tried this code, but not sure how to incorporate the geom_vline. This is my new code using ggplot: ----------------- Covid_19_USA %>% ggplot(aes(x = Dates, y = New_cases)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = Dates)) + geom_vline(data = Covid_19_USA, "2020-05-22")

Comment: I can't manipulate the data as I don't have access to it, you could try geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.Date("2020-05-22"))) to specify a single date.

Comment: @Dealec You're a lifesaver! Thank you so much, but how do I specify multiple dates? like at least 10 dates?

Comment: In that case, remove `aes`: `geom_vline(xintercept=c(as.Date("2020-01-05"),as.Date("2020-04-05")))`